# ?!Have an issue on table using html, css

Tags: html, css

[image]1.) Im having a problem to my table. How can i merge this table into 1? they are separated . see my image below:

css, html

```css
.no-bottom-border{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:100%;

}
```

HTML:

```html
<table class="no-bottom-border">
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Drop</b> : {{$value['sequence_id']}}</td>
                        <td><b>Route Code</b> : {{$value['route_no']}}</td>
                        <td><b>Route Name</b> : {{$route_name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    $getVsr = \App\Modules\Entities\VSR\VSR::where('route_no',$value['route_no'])->get();
                    // dd($getVsr);
                ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                        <th>ENV</th>
                        <th>VSR NO.</th>
                        <th>BOX/BDL</th>
                        <th>SEAL NO.</th>
                        <th>PADLOCK NO.</th>
                        <th>DEST-ATA</th>
                        <th>DEST-ATD</th>
                        <th>REMARKS</th>
                        <th>RECEIVED BY/DATE</th>
                    </tr>
                @foreach($getVsr as $vsrVal)
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{{$vsrVal['env']}}</td>
                        <td>{{$vsrVal['vsr_no']}}</td>
                        <td>{{$vsrVal['vsr_no']}}</td>
                        <td>{{$vsrVal['seal_no']}}</td>
                        <td>{{$vsrVal['padlock_no']}}</td>
                        <td>__________</td>
                        <td>__________</td>
                        <td>__________</td>
                        <td>__________</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </table>
```

any idea? suggestion . much appreciate
2.) i cant fix my table and having a problem to merge it into 1 table only

Answer (score 0):

You have a second `<table>` tag inside your table right below the `<td colspan="3">`

If you only want to have one table, remove the second tag.

Comment: Hi. If i remove colspan  the output will be this:

Comment: oh . i cant upload picture . but the output would be separate tables on Drop Id to Route Name only. and same as Drop 2, drop 3, drop 4